# Tooltip content not displaying

Tags: bootstrap-4, tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

I am using tooltip to display content on mouse-over whatever I wrote in `<li class="li"  data-toggle="tooltip" title="abd">`  title value is displayed.

If I try to write this then no content is visible:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.li').tooltip({Content: "GGTY HJKKKLL"}); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: Is this `li` dynamically created?

Comment: Yes. I'm iterating a repeat tag of visualforce page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used popover instead of tooltip to set the content. In case of tooltip I had to change the content to title.

Answer (score 1):

> Yes. I'm iterating a repeat tag of visualforce page

Your below code will not work for newly created elements.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.li').tooltip({Content: "GGTY HJKKKLL"}); 
});
</script>
```

You need to call below code whenever a new `.li` is added dynamically in the page.

```
 $('.li').tooltip({Content: "GGTY HJKKKLL"});
```

You can have a function like `initTooltips()` and call where ever you want.

```
<script>
 function initTooltips() {
   $('.li').tooltip({Content: "GGTY HJKKKLL"}); 
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    initTooltips();
});
</script>
```

Call `initTooltips()` after the new elements are added.

Comment: Thanks Kiran! It worked, just one issue it is not taking this css like here in example.  : https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_tooltip&stacked=h 
Does this not pick the css automatically? I will mark the answer but please if you can help on this.

Comment: @shuklayogesh are you using bootstrap tooltip or jquery ui tooltip? The example you provided above uses Bootstrap tooltip. CSS should apply automatically both for existing and newly created elements

Comment: Sorry Kiran. Actually it didn't work somehow I missed to comment the title in li and values were coming from there. No luck with using tooltip ({Content: 'XYZ'}) 
I want to use bootstrap tooltip to get good ui.. I have imported bootstrap library in page. Not sure what else is needed.

Comment: Can you change `Content` to `content` in your code. c -> small letter . Bootstrap tooltips are pretty straight forward https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/